# Random Text From jQuery Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make an array of strings and then pluck a random string and place it in a div with class "quote". Below is my current code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var quotes = new Array("foo", "bar", "baz", "chuck");
    var randno = Math.floor ( Math.random() * quotes.length );
    $('.quote').add(quotes[randno]);

});
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Thanks

Comment: What is populating the randno variable

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that line. Just added it.

Comment: Its a JavaScript array, not a jQuery array. And it's better to use `[...]` instead of `new Array(...)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var quotes = new Array("foo", "bar", "baz", "chuck"),
    randno = quotes[Math.floor( Math.random() * quotes.length )];
    $('.quote').text( randno );
});
```

try this

Comment: Haha literally RIGHT before I was gonna post. +1 for similar brainwaves http://jsfiddle.net/byu6V/